# Не могу поднять выше текст, чтоб не сместился блок [css]

Tags: php, css, position

Вот как выглядит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Текст выше должен быть на одном уровне с VS с лева и права соответственно

```css
.match_scoreboard_style {
  position: relative; 
  background-color:#333333;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

.match_scoreboard_versus {
  background:#FF8A00;
  border-radius:25px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:24px;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:71px auto;
  position:relative;
  width:50px;
  z-index:2;
}

.match_scoreboard_left {
  left:0;
  margin-left:-30%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  user-select:none;
  vertical-align:middle;
  will-change:opacity, transform;
  z-index:1;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  height:192px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transform:skew(-30deg);
  width:80%;
}

.match_scoreboard_right {
  margin-right:-30%;
  right:0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  user-select:none;
  vertical-align:middle;
  will-change:opacity, transform;
  z-index:1;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  height:192px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transform:skew(-30deg);
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="match_board_wrapper" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <div class="match_scoreboard_style">     
    <div class="match_scoreboard_versus">VS</div>
    <div class="match_scoreboard_left"></div>
    <div class="match_scoreboard_right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6" style="position: absolute">
    <div class="team_a">
      <div class="match_team">
        <span class="matcg_team_name"><?echo $match['team 1'];?> </span>
        <br/>
        <span id="betsA"> Доделать в X1.46 </span>
      </div>
      <div class="team_img" style="background-image:url('img/event/<?=$post['team 1']?>.jpg')";> </div>
      <div class="team_percent">Тоже доделать в %</div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="team_b">
      <div class="team_percent"> Тоже доделать в %</div>
      <div class="team_img" style="background-image:url('img/event/<?=$post['team 2']?>.jpg')";> </div>
      <div class="match_team">
        <span class="matcg_team_name"><?echo $match['team 2'];?> </span>
        <br/>
        <span id="betsB"> Доделать в X4.26 </span>
      </div>
    </div> 

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Преврати php в html. 2. Сократи до [mcve], а лучше вообще оставь его с нуля. 3. Сделай из кода сниппет (кнопка с `<>` на листике). Тогда можно будет почитать.

Comment: Все, я Обновил! Но я не понял зачем шаг 1) делать

Comment: Чтобы можно было прям в браузере запуустить, поэкспериментироваьт и написать ответ. И ни 1, ни 3, ты не сделал. Сейчас на сниппет тебе поправлю, а ты выпили остатки php, чтобы при запуске получалось то, что у тебя, чтобы это можно было дальше доправить в ответе.

Comment: Я кажется понял, у меня чего-то стиль, связанный с .col не подключается, сейчас изменю вопрос:)